# Scrapy not Downloading Images

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Developer Environment

- `Windows 11`
- `PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1`
- `Python 3.10`

I am following this tutorial [Download Images By Python and Scrapy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJuNdrJIDBo) and I cannot get my script to work.

**spider.py**

```py
import scrapy


class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiki'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Madrid_CF']

    def parse(self, response):   
        urls = response.css('.image img ::attr(src)').getall()
        clean_urls = []

        for url in urls:
            clean_urls.append(response.urljoin(url))
        yield {
            'image_urls':clean_url
        }
```

**settings.py**

```py
BOT_NAME = 'imagedownload'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['imagedownload.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imagedownload.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'images_folder'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

In the tutorial, `items.py`, and `pipelines.py` were not modified. When I run my spider, it runs without errors, and I can see the parsed images urls, however, I the images do not get downloaded:

[image]

**Steps I've taken to resolve the Issue**

1. Set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`
2. Added this snippet to my `spider.py` file

```py
    save_location = os.getcwd()
    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE": save_location
    }
```

3. Tried adding this snippet to `settings.py`

```py
IMAGES_STORE = os.getcwd()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
What I expect is for the script to download images
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  The part that I think is causing is that you have not created the appropriate `Field` for the images results in your yielded dictionary.

I would suggest using a custom scrapy Item with the fields preset, you can do this in the same file as your spider to make it easier, then you should just add all of the `ImagesPipeline` settings to the `custom_settings` dictionary in your `Spider` class.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class Item(scrapy.Item):
    images_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        "IMAGES_STORE" : "images",  # <- make sure whatever you put here is an existing empty folder at the top level of your project.
        "ITEM_PIPELINES" : {"scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline": 1},
        "IMAGES_URLS_FIELD": "images_urls",
        "IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD": "images",
    }

    name = 'wiki'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Madrid_CF']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('.image img ::attr(src)').getall():
            item = Item()
            item['images_urls'] = [response.urljoin(url)]
            yield item
```

Comment: That is pretty cool how you imported everything into the spider class like that! Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Would you mind looking at my [GitHub](https://github.com/lowkey1001100/stackoverflow_issues/blob/main/ImageDownloader/ImageDownloader.zip) files and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance for further assistance!

Comment: change the contents of your wiki spider file to look like my example.... your github repo still looks the exact same as in your question